# How to get Annotation index in Mapkit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, annotations, mapkit

How to get Annotation index in `Mapkit`?

i try so far is...

In `ViewDidLoad` like this...

```
 [self.mapView addAnnotations:[self createAnnotations]];
```

In CreateAnnotations like this....

```
- (NSMutableArray *)createAnnotations
{
    NSMutableArray *annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //Read locations details from plist
    NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"locations" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray * locations = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSDictionary * imageDic;
     customTickLocations = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSDictionary *row in locations) {
        NSNumber *latitude = [row objectForKey:@"latitude"];
        NSNumber *longitude = [row objectForKey:@"longitude"];
        NSString *title = [row objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString * image=[row objectForKey:@"image"];
        imageDic =[row objectForKey:image];
        [customTickLocations addObject:[row objectForKey:@"image"]];

        //Create coordinates from the latitude and longitude values
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
        coord.latitude = latitude.doubleValue;
        coord.longitude = longitude.doubleValue;

        MapViewAnnotation * annotation =[[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:image initWithSubTitle:title AndCoordinate:coord];

               [annotations addObject:annotation];

    }
    NSLog(@"%@",customTickLocations);
    return annotations;
}

   - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
    {
        MapViewAnnotation * annos = view.annotation;


        NSInteger indexOfTheObject = [mapView.annotations indexOfObject: annos];

        NSString * image =[customTickLocations objectAtIndex:indexOfTheObject];
        NSLog(@"------ %ld ------",(long)indexOfTheObject);
    }
```

i am getting index , The Problem is index value is changing for same Pin

Please help me

Comment: Try this: `NSUInteger indexOfTheObject = [mapView.annotations indexOfObject: view.annotation];`

Comment: @BhavinRamani thank you . but the problem is same

Comment: but bhavin it include user current location also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
 NSUInteger index = [mapView.annotations indexOfObject:view.annotation];
  NSLog(@"index no %d",index);
```

you get the index

```
 NSInteger i = 0;
 for (NSDictionary *row in locations) {
        NSNumber *latitude = [row objectForKey:@"latitude"];
        NSNumber *longitude = [row objectForKey:@"longitude"];
        NSString *title = [row objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString * image=[row objectForKey:@"image"];
        imageDic =[row objectForKey:image];
        [customTickLocations addObject:[row objectForKey:@"image"]];

        //Create coordinates from the latitude and longitude values
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
        coord.latitude = latitude.doubleValue;
        coord.longitude = longitude.doubleValue;

        MapViewAnnotation * annotation =[[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:image initWithSubTitle:title AndCoordinate:coord Withindex:i];

 i++;
               [annotations addObject:annotation];

    }
```

plz add one more property in MapViewAnnotation for index then try.

Comment: can you show how your are useing -(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation

Comment: Thank you . i am get correct index value but the problem is changing the index randomly.

Comment: i am using separate class like for MapViewAnnotation like this..-(id) initWithTitle:(NSString *) title  initWithSubTitle:(NSString *) imgTitle AndCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    self =  [super init];
    _title = title;
    _coordinate = coordinate;
    _imgTitle = imgTitle;
    return self;
}

Comment: i am getting index ... but the index is changing time of running  the app

Comment: co-ordinates are static

Comment: you use a extra property for index in your separate class

Comment: co-ordinates  static means you are useing same co-ordinates  for all pins.

Comment: how can i get index in - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view

Comment: i add the With index property but how can i use this in didSelectAnnotationView

Answer (score 2):

Try like this;

Annotation is your custom class that holds information about the annotation

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
{

 if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[Annotation class]]) 
{
        Annotation *annos = view.annotation;

        NSInteger index = [self.arrayOfAnnotations indexOfObject:annos];

    NSString * image =[customTickLocations objectAtIndex:indexOfTheObject];
    NSLog(@"------ %ld ------",(long)indexOfTheObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you . i am get correct  index value but the problem is changing the index randomly..

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view{

    NSInteger indexOfTheObject = [mapView.annotations indexOfObject:view.annotation];

}
```