# How to get annotation indexpath in mapview

Tags: ios, objective-c, annotations, mkmapview

I have a problem.
I have a mapView, and I have many annotations in my mapView.
how to know the `indexPath` that I select the annotation.
I find the function `didSelectAnnotationView` but I don't know how to use it.

This is my code:

```
 BOOL firstLocationReceived;

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations
{
    CLLocation *currentLocation = locations.lastObject; //current location

    if(firstLocationReceived == NO)
    {
        MKCoordinateRegion region = _shopMapView.region;
        region.center = currentLocation.coordinate;
        region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.05;
        region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.05;

        [_restaurantMapView setRegion:region animated:true];

        //Add Annotation

        for (int i = 0; i < self.items.count ; i++) 
        {
            MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [MKPointAnnotation new];

            NSDictionary *item = self.items[i];

            CLLocationDegrees latitude = [item[@"latitude"] doubleValue];
            CLLocationDegrees longitude = [item[@"longitude"] doubleValue];

            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
            annotation.title = item[@"name"];
            annotation.subtitle = item[@"address"];

            [_shopMapView addAnnotation:annotation];

          firstLocationReceived == YES;
        }
    }
}

-(MKAnnotationView*)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if (annotation == mapView.userLocation)
    {
        return nil;
    }

    NSString *identifier = @"shop";

    MKAnnotationView *result = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if(result ==nil)
    {
        result = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }
    else
    {
        result.annotation = annotation;
    }
    result.canShowCallout = true;

    UIImage *annotationViewImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"point.png"];
    result.image = annotationViewImage;

    result.leftCalloutAccessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:annotationViewImage];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    result.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button;

    return result;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369328/detecting-the-selected-map-annotation-xcode

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156800/how-to-get-annotation-index-in-mapkit/38157106#38157106 see this

Answer (score 0):

- You can get your selected annotation index by this way,

  ```
  -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view{
       MKPointAnnotation * annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
       annotation = view.annotation;
       NSString * selectedTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",annotation.title];
       NSInteger index = [[self.items valueForKey:@"name"] indexOfObject:selectedTitle]; //Considering self.items as NSDictionary consist of all annotation names.
       NSLog(@"You selected index: %ld",(long)index);
  }
  ```

  **Swift**

  ```
  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
      var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
      if let anAnnotation = view.annotation as? MKPointAnnotation {
         annotation = anAnnotation
      }
      let selectedTitle = "\(annotation.title ?? "")"
      let index: Int? = (items["name"] as? NSArray)?.index(of: selectedTitle)
      //Considering self.items as NSDictionary consist of all annotation names.
      print("You selected index: \(Int(index))")
  }
  ```
- Get the `annotation title` of selected annotation point and lets find it's index in our array of all names.

Comment: @imbeginner_sorry did you checked it..?

Comment: May you provide a Swift example?

Comment: @DaniSpringer Yeah sure.. Please check updated answer